# How to change a cshtml web pag dropdwon to a combobox with text input

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web, razor

I have a section of a cshtml web page that has a dropdown box, but I need to use a combobox with a input instead.

Here is the code to populate the dropdown box.

I am new to web development so any feedback is appreciated.
Thank you in advance

```
 $.getJSON("/orders/orderlist/picks", function (picks) {
                picks.forEach(function (item) {
                    $('#ordermodifpick').append('<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>');
                });
              
            });
```

I tried many suggestions from the web with not success.

Comment: I'm not aware of any native HTML element which provides this functionality.  You'd need to either build something custom or use a 3rd party component/plugin/etc.  (For example, if you're using jQuery then you can search for "jQuery combobox" on your favorite search engine to find relevant plugins to use.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is what you want, Here is a simple combobox demo, When user input value in `input` tag, He can select an option in dropdown box directly and `input` tag can filter the options in the datalist based on the user's input.

```
<input type="text" list="ordermodifpick" id="ordermodifpick-input">
<datalist id="ordermodifpick"></datalist>

<script>
        $.getJSON("/orders/orderlist/picks", function (picks) {
            picks.forEach(function (item) {
                $('#ordermodifpick').append(`<option value="${item}">`);
            });
        });

        $('#ordermodifpick-input').on('input', function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $('#ordermodifpick option').filter(function () {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Demo:

[image]

I hope this answer can solve your issue.

Comment: Hi @Tom, Have this answer solved your issue?